# Safari display animations incorrect from added CSS class via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have problem with Safari browser. In code below, I have several animations(scroll to ID and incerase height of element - if clicked), and when last coming to end, on complete of last animation, jQuery is adding class to nested element('opened'). CSS should animate this nested element with visibility, scale and transformY. On all browsers script works really good (chrome, moz, opera) but on safari not really... **Nested element only shows up, when I take mouseOut from `<li>` element, which is contain animated nested element.**  Actually I have more than one problem, but I will replace other bugged elements... I havent JS fiddle with this element, because there is to much of code, and nested styles.

My Code JS:

```
on('click'...)
if( $( this ).css( "height" ) == "270px" ) {                    
                    list.removeClass("active");
                    inner.removeClass("opened");
                    list.animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                    $(this).animate({height: maxHeight }, 
                    { 
                    duration: 500, 
                    complete: function() {
                        $($this_li).addClass("active");
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top },
                            {
                                duration:  500,
                                complete: function() {
                                     $($this_li).find(".inner").addClass("opened");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }...
```

and CSS:

```
.inner {
                    position: absolute;
                    display:block;
                    padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
                    left:0;
                    right:0;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    margin-right:auto;
                    bottom: 5%;
                    width: 80%;
                    z-index:100;
                    background:#333;
                    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
                    -moz-transition: all .5s;
                    -o-transition: all .5s;
                    -ms-transition: all .5s;
                    transition: all .5s;
                    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) translateY(150%);
                    -moz-transform: scale(1.3) translateY(150%);
                    -o-transform: scale(1.3) translateY(150%);
                    -ms-transform: scale(1.3) translateY(150%);
                    transform: scale(1.3) translateY(150%);
                    opacity: 0;
                    visibility: hidden;}

.inner.opened {
                    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
                    -moz-transform:scale(1);
                    -o-transform:scale(1);
                    -ms-transform:scale(1);
                    transform:translateY(0%);
                    -moz-transform:translateY(0%);
                    -o-transform:translateY(0%);
                    -ms-transform:translateY(0%);
                    transform:translateY(0%);
                    z-index: 200;
                    opacity: 0.9;
                    visibility: visible;}
```

I am really confused, because today I really wanted to put site live, and because od damn Safari, I cant do this. I wil be thankful for any hints! PS. apologise for language mistakes.